# Querying database, null Column values?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I'm having a user login then it calls the controller. I search the User table for an email match and save it to a User variable. But the Permissions column is null when I try to check if it is an admin user or not, its a null reference.

Why doesn't the user first or default pull all the column data, I check in the database and the permissionId is there, but pulling it as null when I check the value of said row.

I'm really knew, my first bigger project and the first time I couldn't seem to find an answer googling around.

this is the entities:

User:

```
public class User
    {
        public int    UserId        { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR(100)")]
        [StringLength(100)]
        [Required]
        public string FirstName     { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR(100)")]
        [StringLength(100)]
        [Required]
        public string LastName      { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR(100)")]
        [StringLength(250)]
        [Required]
        public string Email         { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Password      { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string UserName      { get; set; }



        //The user can have many posts 
        public List<Post> Post      { get; set; }
        public virtual Permissions Permissions { get; set; }
    }
```

Permissions:

```
public class Permissions
    {
        public int PermissionsID {get; set;}
        [Required]
        public bool admin { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public bool StandUser { get; set; }

        //Many Users can have a permission, this makes the foreign key for the Post Table.
        public List<User> User { get; set; }


    }
```

This is the the login Post controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Login(LoginViewModel loginViewModel)
        {
            //We're grabbing the plain text password so we can hash it later. 
            loginViewModel.plainTextPassword = loginViewModel.user.Password;


            //Searching for the users emaill address and gathering the user information. 
            User userInfo = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == loginViewModel.user.Email);



            //if the user information is null, then we don't have the user information. 
            if (userInfo == null)
            {
                ViewBag.Error = "Sorry, but we couldn't log you in.";
                return View();
            }
            else if (Hashing.Confirm(loginViewModel.plainTextPassword, userInfo.Password, Supported_Ha.SHA256))
            {
                //Were building the user session information
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("UserFirstName", userInfo.FirstName);
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("UserLastName", userInfo.LastName);
                HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("UserUserId", loginViewModel.user.UserId);


                if (userInfo.Permissions.admin == true)
                {
                    HttpContext.Session.SetString("IsAdmin", "true");
                }
                else
                {
                    HttpContext.Session.SetString("IsAdmin", "false");
                }


                ViewBag.IsAdmin = HttpContext.Session.GetString("IsAdmin");
                ViewBag.SessionUserName = HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserFirstName");
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.Error = "Sorry, but we couldn't log you in.";
            return View("Index");



        }
```

I expected the userInfo to have all the rows not be null so I later can check if the user is a Admin or not.

Comment: Navigation properties (I assume `Permissions` is a such) need to be included explicitly `_context.Users.Include(user => user.Permissions).FirstOrDefault(user => user.Email == loginViewModel.user.Email);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally lazy-loading would have taken care of this behind the scenes, but if you don't have that enabled or available (pre EF Core 2.1) you will be left with #null references.

Options:

1) Eager load Permissions with `.Include(x => x.Permissions)`.

As Fabio commented above, this should solve your immediate issue. The consideration with eager loading is that you have to explicitly include everything you want to reference, and that can mean loading a lot more data than you need.

2) Use `Select` to get the data you need.

By leveraging `Select` you can remove the need to worry about eager loading or lazy load hits and generate SQL that will be optimized to return just the data you care about. In the case where you want to perform some logic based on the data state you can use Anonymous types to represent the data. In other cases where you want to return data to a view, use Select (or Automapper's `ProjectTo`) to populate a view model.

For example:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Login(LoginViewModel loginViewModel)
{
    loginViewModel.plainTextPassword = loginViewModel.user.Password;

    var userInfo = _context.Users.Where(x => x.Email == loginViewModel.user.Email)
        .Select(x => new 
        {
            x.UserId,
            x.FirstName,
            x.LastName,
            x.Password,
            IsAdmin = x.Permissions.Admin
        }).SingleOrDefault();

    if (userInfo == null)
    {
        ViewBag.Error = "Sorry, but we couldn't log you in.";
        return View();
    }
    else if (Hashing.Confirm(loginViewModel.plainTextPassword, userInfo.Password, Supported_Ha.SHA256))
    {
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("UserFirstName", userInfo.FirstName);
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("UserLastName", userInfo.LastName);
        HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("UserUserId", userInfo.UserId);


        HttpContext.Session.SetString("IsAdmin", userInfo.IsAdmin.ToString());

        ViewBag.IsAdmin = userInfo.IsAdmin.ToString();
        ViewBag.SessionUserName = userInfo.FirstName;
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    ViewBag.Error = "Sorry, but we couldn't log you in.";
    return View("Index");
}
```

Keynotes: We use Select to retrieve just the columns from the User that we need, (name, ID, password hash) plus the "admin" flag from their Permissions reference. This is loaded into a temporary container that we can reference in this method. It's best to use `Single`/`SingleOrDefault` whenever you are expecting a single row rather than `First`/`FirstOrDefault` since unexpected duplicate data scenarios can be masked. IMO `First`/`FirstOrDefault` should never be used without an `OrderBy` clause to ensure consistent results.

Comment: This sounds correct, will give it a try when I get home tonight from work.

Comment: I had to do a little tweaking for what I needed, but it did the job, thanks!